# Tomcat Server Error Message - Current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exist

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, tomcat9, java-12

crud.war is copied to tomcat webapps folder and I have started tomcat server. I have executed rest command from SOAPUI. It is working Java 1.8 and Tomcat Server 8.0.52 version but it is not running other machine which is configured Java 12 and Tomcat Server version 9.0.22 version. It is showing different error message while running different java and tomcat version. ***Please let me know why is it not running in Java 12 and Tomcat Server 9.0.22 version ?***

Error Message with Java 12 and Tomcat Server 9.0.22

"The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exist"

Error Message with Java 1.8 and Tomcat Server 8.0.52

"The requested resource is not available."

***Java 12 & Tomcat 9 : Error Message
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Message /crud/
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/9.0.22***

---

***Java 8 & Tomcat 8 : Error Message
HTTP Status 404 - /crud/
type Status report
message /crud/
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.52***

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: The below error message is showing in Catalina.out log files. Other sample services is running successfully except CRUD.War. I am unable to upload full log files.   "MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
 implementation=org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.DataSourceProvider
 contracts={javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter,javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader}
 scope=javax.inject.Singleton
 qualifiers={}
 descriptorType=CLASS
 descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
 metadata=
 rank=0

Comment: Looks like a Jersey error to me. You might want to add the "Jersey" tag to this question.

Comment: Where will i add Jersey tag?  Do you want add tomcat server or crud.war file ?